# How to make a non static callback in c++?

Tags: callback, delegates

I'm not as good in C++ as I want to, more C# man.

So, please tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it?

```
// I've declared base class and event handler for it.
// Some sort of delegate simulation
class IEventable {};
typedef void (*EventHandler)(IEventable*);

//Used this event in class I wand to call back to invoker
class Timer : IEventable {
private:
  EventHandler _onTimer;

  ...

  void OnEvent() {
    ...
    if (_onTimer) _onTimer(this);
  }
public:
  ...
  void Start(uint32_t interval, EventHandler onTimer) {
    ...
    
  }
}

// Holder of timer
class Invoker {
private:
  // I've put it here for now from timers creator method
  Timer* _timer = new Timer();

  void _onOpenTimer(Timer timer) {
    ...
  }

  void _open() {
    ...

    // And here I have compilation error about wrong use of
    // non static member 'void Invoker::_onOpenTimer(Timer)'
    _timer.Start(500, _onOpenTimer);
  }
}
```

I have more than one timer and want to determine whitch one is calling back.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I did a workaround with statics. Don't know how well it will work but...

```
    // I've declared base class and event handler for it.
    // Some sort of delegate simulation
    class IEventable {};
    class IEventer {};
    typedef void (*EventHandler)(IEventable*, IEventer*);
    
    //Used this event in class I wand to call back to invoker
    class Timer : public IEventable {
    private:
      IEventer* _eventer;
      EventHandler _onTimer;
    
      ...
    
      void OnEvent() {
        ...
        if (_onTimer) _onTimer(this, eventer);
      }
    public:
      ...
      void Start(uint32_t interval, IEventer* eventer, EventHandler onTimer) {
        _eventer = eventer;
        ...
        
      }
    }
    
    // Timer parent
    class Invoker : public IEventer {
    private:
      // I've put it here for now from timers creator method
      Timer* _timer = new Timer();
    
      static void _onOpenTimer(IEventable* sender, IEventer* enenter) {
        eventer->OnOpenTimer(sender);
      }
    
      void _open() {
        ...
    
        _timer.Start(500, this, _onOpenTimer);
      }

    public:
      void OnOpenTimer(Timer* sender) {
        ...
      }
    };
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).